# Select greater of two (calculated) date values

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have two date columns `Date A` and `Date B`.

I need to select the greater (most recent) of `Date A + 42 Days` and `Date B`.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Yes. I want the LATEST date out of ColumnA+42days and ColumnB of my table, as another column added to the select * statement.

Comment: I cleaned up the questoin.

Comment: @PrateekGangopadhyay That is NOT sample data. Sample data includes ddl and dml statement to create/populate a table with actual sample data and what resultset you desire from that sample data. Put that information into your original question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple CASE statement:

```
SELECT A, B, CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, 42, A) > B THEN DATEADD(DAY, 42, A) ELSE B END AS A42ORB
```

There are other ways depending on the SQL Server version for example:

```
SELECT A, B, CA.C
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(V) AS C
    FROM (VALUES
        (DATEADD(DAY, 42, A)),
        (B)
    ) AS VA(V)
) AS CA
```

Or:

```
SELECT A, B, CASE WHEN C > B THEN C ELSE B END
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 42, A)) AS CA(C)
```

Comment: I was giving an alias for the Dateadd value. This was giving me the error.

Comment: Yes alias won't work like that. If you must then you could add the alias inside a `CROSS APPLY` like `SELECT A, B, CASE WHEN C > B THEN C ELSE B END FROM ... CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 42, A)) AS CA(C)`

Answer (score 0):

For latest date use `MAX()` to find A+42 days use `DATEADD()` . If you can give us table structure and expected result we can help you better.
Here is example:

```
SELECT  MAX([YourDateColumn]) 
FROM    YourTable 
WHERE   [YourDateColumn] BETWEEN B AND DATEADD(DAY,42,A)
```

Comment: DDL for the table like Create table temp UNIQUESOID nvarchar(20), SoCreateDate(DATETIME), SOSUBMISSIONDATE(DATETIME)

Comment: @PrateekGangopadhyay Which date you want find as latest and which date you want to search.

Answer (score 0):

I'd give this a go, hope it helps!

```
SELECT 
MAX([a])

FROM    
(SELECT DATEADD(DD,42,SoCreateDate) [a]
FROM UNIQUESOID
UNION ALL
SELECT SOSUBMISSIONDATE
FROM UNIQUESOID 

) [x]
```

Just to explain what this script does;
Create a combined set of data (using union) so that the two dates are in the same column then we use `SELECT (MAX)` in order to pick the highest value from that dataset we just created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your question was well understood by the others, so let me propose you this solution :

```
SELECT
    IIF(DATEADD(DAY,42,t0.A) > t0.B, DATEADD(DAY,42,t0.A), t0.B) AS MaxDate
FROM
    YourTable  AS t0
```

WARNING : If you have possibility of NULL values for your dates, you have to handle the case in your IIF